# Unable to resolve module for local file (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I'm bizarrely getting an error that a local file import can't be resolved by React Native.

```
Unable to resolve module `./components/MyComponent" from ".//App.js`: could not resolve `/Users/myusername/Desktop/mylibrary/components/MyComponent' as a file nor as a folder","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]},"type":"bundling_error"}"
```

mylibrary/App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native';

import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent';
```

mylibrary/components/MyComponent.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        <View>
            {this.props.children}
        </View>
    }
}
```

I tried renaming the file to be lowercase (`mycomponent.jsx`), and it didn't make a difference. I also tried restarting my simulator and resetting the cache, and it also didn't help.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the `import` statement by default try to import `.js` files, try renaming `MyComponent.jsx` to `MyComponent.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component is wrong. You are not returning anything in the render method. Try this:

```
render() {

return(
        <View>
            {this.props.children}
        </View>
)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `import` statement by default try to import `.js` files, try renaming `MyComponent.jsx` to `MyComponent.js`.

Quoting the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

> The module to import from. This is often a relative or absolute path name to the .js file containing the module, excluding the .js extension. Certain bundlers may permit or require the use of the extension; check your environment. Only single quotes and double quotes Strings are allowed.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. :( Error becomes `Unable to resolve module './components/mycomponent.js' from ".//App.js': could not resolve /Users/myusername/Desktop/mylibrary/components/mycomponent' as a file nor as a folder","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]},"type":"bundling_error"}"`

Comment: @zahabba You changed the filename to lowercase? Make sure the filename case match the one you're trying to import.